# In MVVM is it acceptable to access the ViewModel in the view's code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, datacontext

IN an MVVM pattern is it acceptable or even possible to access ViewModel properties in the  views code behind?

I have an observable collection which is populated in the ViewModel. I need to use it in the view to bind to an endless ticker with a linked list. i.e.

```
    private LinkedList<Border> tickerForex = new LinkedList<Border>();

    public ForexBuy()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ForexViewModel();
    }

    private void InitializeForexTicker()
    {
        CanvasForexBuyTicker.Children.Clear();
        foreach (var currency in DataContext.Currencies) //Is this possible/allowable???
        {
           AddTickerItem(currency);
        }

        CanvasForexBuyTicker.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
        { var node = tickerForex.First;

            while (node != null)
            {
                if (node.Previous != null)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(node.Value, Canvas.GetLeft(node.Previous.Value) + node.Previous.Value.ActualWidth + gap);
                }
                else
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(node.Value, CanvasForexBuyTicker.Width + gap);
                }

                node = node.Next;
            }

            return null;

        }), null);

}

void AddTickerItem(Currency currency)
    {
        Border border = new Border();
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 99, 99));

        if (currency.IsUpward == 0)
        {
            border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 153, 0));
        }

        border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
        border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        border.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10);
        border.Width = Double.NaN;
        border.Height = 35;

        UIHelper.CanvasAutoSize canvas = new UIHelper.CanvasAutoSize();
        canvas.Background = Brushes.Green;  
        canvas.Tag = currency;
        canvas.Height = Double.NaN;

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock
        {
            Text = currency.Code + " " + currency.Sell + " ",
            FontSize = 22,
            FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
            Foreground = Brushes.Black
        };

        tb.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 8d);
        tb.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 2d);
        canvas.Children.Add(tb);

        tb.TouchDown += TouchTickerItem;

        border.Child = canvas;

        CanvasForexBuyTicker.Children.Add(border);
        Canvas.SetTop(CanvasForexBuyTicker, 3);
        Canvas.SetLeft(CanvasForexBuyTicker, 0);

        tickerForex.AddLast(border);
    }
```

I'm a little lost as to whether the dispatcher should fire from the ViewModel or whether to use it in the views code behind.

Comment: Why can't you just bind straight to the list in the `ViewModel`?

Comment: Can't see how that helps. 'CanvasForexBuyTicker' needs the dispatcher attached and the ViewModel doesn't (shouldn't) know about the canvas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the question is just about *how* to access the ViewModel from code behind, you could simply cast the DataContext to the proper type:

```
var viewModel = (MyViewModel)DataContext;

foreach (var currency in viewModel.Currencies)
{
    ...
}
```

If this is acceptable or not is a matter of taste. I do not see any fundamental difference in accessing the view model by bindings in the view's XAML or by a piece of code-behind.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: NO.

you're not supposed to place business or Model specific code in the code behind. Only VIEW-specific code should be placed in code behind.

Why are you declaring a `List<Border>`. Sounds weird to me. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It's list border because the items on the ticker are TextBlocks set in a Canvas set in a border. I understand that you shouldn't place business logic in the code behind. Wouldn't a dispatcher fired like this be part of the view logic? e.g. because it's endless I have to keep checking if the last one is coming into view and append the first node again.

Comment: @JohnSourcer that's what an `ItemsControl` is meant for. I'm trying to get my head around in order to understand what you're trying to do here, but I can't

Comment: thanks for looking. I've edited to the code above to try clarify.

Comment: @HighCore Could you please provide any reference for that strict no? Personally i think you're not right here, and i tend to say the exact opposite: Yes, it is absolutely OK to access viewmodel properties in the view's code-behind, in the same sense as it is perfectly OK to access viewmodel properties in the view's bindings. But maybe you tell us where you get your opinion from. And we're not talking about model properties here, but about viewmodel properties.

Comment: @Clemens maybe i'm wrong. Its just that I don't completely understand what the OP is doing here, by declaring some `List<Border>` in code... maybe I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @HighCore But the fact that you do not fully understand the question does *in no way* justify that "Short answer: NO". You should either edit or remove this answer.

Comment: I agree, it is not unreasonable to have to have code in the code behind for a view. As long as it deals with how to display the data, and not how to calculate or load the data etc. I've had to do this when dealing with hosted windows forms controls that do not support data binding, or when significant conversion has to take place in order to display it on a graph, and that conversion was specific to that control.

Comment: Conceptually speaking, the viewmodel exists to act as an intersection of responsibilities between the view's physical construction and the abstract model data it is displaying. Therefore of course it makes sense that it be accessed from the view, as the only reason it exists is to support that view. Simply accessing it does not constitute a pollution of the view's responsibility with business logic—the actual business logic should happen in the model anyway, not the viewmodel.

Comment: The viewmodel is really only there to offload some of the responsibility of the view into another file; since its logic is uniquely tied to the view, it does not really represent an abstraction per se.