# Detecting property changes on a datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext, inotifypropertychanged

A further question to Clemen's fine answer here: [DataContext values in view code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753228/datacontext-values-in-view-code-behind). If one used this approach, is it possible to detect property changes on the VM at this point? These are correctly implemented through `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
var viewModel = DataContext as MyViewModel;
//How would one detect a property change on viewModel?
//Tried viewModel.PropertyChange which doesn't fire.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must be doing something wrong that you're not mentioning in your post. The following code works as expected and will print MyTestPropertyName to the Console window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyViewModel viewModel = DataContext as MyViewModel;
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += MyPropertyChangedEventHandler;
        viewModel.NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }

    private void MyPropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);
    }

}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged()
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyTestPropertyName"));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

It should be noted that this is TERRIBLE design, and is only designed as a proof of concept, that you can indeed subscribe to events on the ViewModel in the code-behind.

Comment: Thanks Takkara, I understand why this is terrible design but am unsure on how to improve it. I have markers on a 3D sphere and when a user selects one I'm joining them with a line. I'm doing the line calculations in the view code behind and my viewmodel knows when the selected point has changed thus the question.

Comment: this works when you trigger the change as you do using: viewModel.NotifyPropertyChanged(); but it doesn't seem to work if the change was triggered via the UI. A button click in the UI triggers the change notification on the VM itself but that change never reflects in viewModel.PropertyChanged += MyPropertyChangedEventHandler;

Comment: This is the correct answer. Noting that it is a bad design practice.

Comment: John, I suspect that you've simply implemented INotifyPropertyChanged but you have not added the code that triggers the event. It is not sufficient to simply implement the interface. You must raise the event from the setter of each bound property as well as in any other methods that might affect the values of properties that are bound.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to either subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event of each dependency property (I.e. the properties that implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`), or modify your `MyViewModel` class to raise an event from the setters of the properties (dependency or otherwise) that you are interested in being notified about, and then subscribe to the common event.